# difference between Html.TextBox and Html.TextBoxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

What is the difference between Html.TextBox and Html.TextBoxFor? As far as I know they produce same html output. Unless I'm missing something here. Please help me with this.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908523/html-textbox-vs-html-textboxfor

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`Html.TextBox` is not strongly typed and it doesn't require a strongly typed view meaning that you can hardcode whatever name you want as first argument and provide it a value:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("foo", "some value") %>
```

You can set some value in the `ViewData` dictionary inside the controller action and the helper will use this value when rendering the textbox (`ViewData["foo"] = "bar"`).

`Html.TextBoxFor` is requires a strongly typed view and uses the view model:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Foo) %>
```

The helper will use the lambda expression to infer the name and the value of the view model passed to the view.

And because it is a good practice to use strongly typed views and view models you should always use the `Html.TextBoxFor` helper.

Comment: So, I assume the end result is same. Pl correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @gmail user, yes the end result is the same. They both emit the same html.

Answer (score 0):

Strongly typed extensions is to show any errors or warnings at compile time rather than run time. Please see [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-2-strongly-typed-html-helpers) page, it will clarify all your doubts