# ASP.NET MVC 3 Lambda (=>) Syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Please, can anyone tell me what the meaning of => operator in Html helper syntax.

Eg: `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`m => m.Username` is equivalent to providing a method, something like

```
string GetUserName(TypeOfModel m)
{
   return m.UserName;
}
```

However, because [TextBoxFor takes an Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703644.aspx), it is able to 'parse' the lambda and is able to infer that the name of the TextBox input should be ['Name'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908523/html-textbox-vs-html-textboxfor) (viz the property scraped off the model). This is important and 'intuitive', since the MVC ModelBinder will then be able to map "Name" to a property or parameter when it is next sent back to a controller.

Answer (score 5):

It's not specific to the Razor engine. That is a C# lambda expression.