# Error: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Error:Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

I am getting this error when I am trying to add in cshtml page in mvc4.
at line

Customer Name: @Html.TextBox(m => Model.CustomerName)

Could anyone explain what is its meaning and why it comes here?

Code is

```
@model DataEntryMvcApplication.Models.Customer
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>Customer Name: @Html.TextBox(m => Model.CustomerName)</p>
    <p>ID:@Html.TextBox(m=>Model.CustomerId)</p>
    <input type="submit" name="Custtomer" />
}
```

and this is model class;

```
namespace DataEntryMvcApplication.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public string CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need Html.TextBoxFor instead of Html.TextBox:

```
@model DataEntryMvcApplication.Models.Customer
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>Customer Name: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CustomerName)</p>
    <p>ID:@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CustomerId)</p>
}
```

The difference between the two is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908523/html-textbox-vs-html-textboxfor)

Answer (score 1):

`Model` doesn't exist in the linq expression which is the parameter of `@Html.TextBox(...)`. The `m` represents the `Model` and you need to use that variable to access the correct properties, like here:

```
<p>Customer Name: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CustomerName)</p>
<p>ID:@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.CustomerId)</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
@model DataEntryMvcApplication.Models.Customer
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>Customer Name: @Html.TextBox(m => m.CustomerName)</p>
    <p>ID:@Html.TextBox(m=>m.CustomerId)</p>
    <input type="submit" name="Custtomer" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just spent ages trying to solve this.  After restoring old pages and making changes one by one, it appears the line causing the problem is:

```
<img src="~/images/Captcha/@ViewBag("CaptchaName")" />
```

I think it must not like attempts to access the view bag?  Whatever, commenting this out solved the problem.