# How to bind a value to a text box in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, textbox

I have a problem when I want to bind a value from my model to a textbox, here is my MVC view code:

```
@Html.TextBox("SellerBroker", model => model.OutOfMarket.BuyerBroker.Name , new { @class = "control-label" })
```

I want my textbox to have a name or 'SellerBroker' and it's value to come from my model property `model => model.OutOfMarket.BuyerBroker.Name` and with HTML attributes of `class = "control-label"`.  However, I am receiving the following error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: `@Html.TextBox("SellerBroker", Model.OutOfMarket.BuyerBroker.Name , new { @class = "control-label" })` but why would you do this instead of binding to your property - `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OutOfMarket.BuyerBroker.Name , new { @class = "control-label" })`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helper `@Html.TextBox()` does not contain overloard that have lambda parameter. You should use it without lambda like this like @Stephen Muecke advice you:

```
@Html.TextBox("SellerBroker", Model.OutOfMarket.BuyerBroker.Name , new { @class = "control-label" })
```

If you want to use lambda you should use `@Html.TextBoxFor()` helper. But you should change name like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OutOfMarket.BuyerBroker.Name, new { Name = "SellerBroker", @class = "control-label"})
```

Answer (score 1):

The `@Html.TextBox()` can be used for generating a textbox with an initial value (one way binding).

If you want to really bind the textbox to your class property (two ways binding), you should use the `@Html.TextBoxFor()` helper. This method take as parameter a lambda expression, as used in your example.

You can found more details on TextBox helpers at : [Html.Textbox VS Html.TextboxFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908523/html-textbox-vs-html-textboxfor)